# How are PhoneGap, SMS and Push Notifications related?

Tags: cordova, push-notification, sms, phonegap-plugins

This might sounds like a really obvious question, but I've been unable to confirm anything in all my googling. I'm really new to mobile development and I'm just trying to understand the theory behind how all this relates to each other.

If I have a mobile app (created in PhoneGap/Cordova) that talks to my API (.NET), and I want my backend to send out notifications to my users, am I correct for the following assumptions:

1. sending a text message (3rd party service) has nothing to do with my mobile app if I'm just sending it straight to the phone number of the device, and it will just show up in their text messaging app like any text message would. No plugins or coding on the mobile app side needed.
2. sending a push notification will require that I have some kind of plugin for PhoneGap on my app that will accept the notification from the 3rd party service that my backend requested to send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending a SMS is generally just a simple HTTP request to a third party able to send a SMS. So any client or server can do it. The SMS will just be sent as any normal SMS.

Sending a push notification is generally done from a server since it's also a simple HTTP request but with a really strong authentication. But it could be done from any client in fact.

Indeed, receiving a push notification has to be managed by your app via a specific plugin able to manage that. You have 3 states :

- your app is closed
- your app is in background
- your app is active

Depending on this state, you can "react" in various ways.